# Как правильно задать стили через v-bind во Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

Все привет. 
Пытаюсь задать ширину для блоков, но почему то не подцепляется. прошу Подсказать, что не так делаю.

```js
//Данные


data: {
        workspacewidth: {
            width: '85%;'
        },
        menuwidth: {
            width: '15%;'
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="block-menu"  v-bind:style='menuwidth'>
</div>
<div class="block-workspace"  v-bind:style='workspacewidth'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя точка с запятой (`;`) в стилях. Не надо))

```
data: {
  workspacewidth: {
      width: '85%'
  },
  menuwidth: {
      width: '15%'
  }
}
```

Comment: Это только проблема в данных. Если поле исправления этой ошибки не выйдет - смотри в спомпилированные стили и проведи аудит позиционирования своих блоков, но это уже не Vue, а `css`

Comment: блин, 2 часа убил на это. Огромное спасибо!